# btrfs subvolume: do I really need to mount them?

Tags: filesystems, mount, btrfs

Say I have a device /dev/sda1, I format it into a btrfs filesystem:

```
mkfs.btrfs /dev/sda1
```

Then I mount it:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Then I create a subvolume:

```
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/subvol1
```

at this point I can already use the subvolume right? like storing a file in it.
Do I really need to mount it?
Why would I mount it?  (maybe because some people want to mount different subvolumes with different options? If I don't care about that, do I still need to mount subvolume? )

(a little background of this question is, on some Linux machines, I would see `/`, `/var`, `/tmp` being subvolumes of same device, `mount` would show `/var` as mounted, but after researching on Google for quite a while, I still don't get why `/var` needs to be mounted at all as it would become available as soon as `/` is mounted).

Comment: You got the gist of it correct. I have tons of subvolumes, but only mount the ones that point to separate partitions.

Comment: thanks for sharing that. I got quite confused since I didn't find this discussed anywhere. Most articles about it are like, now you create a subvolume, now you mount it. Upon reading it I'm like why? why why? isn't it already present as a subfolder? why mount it?

Comment: A common example I see is creating a subvolume for `/var/cache`. This subvolume is created at the root volume level - like `/mnt/@cache` - then mounted at `/mnt/var/cache`. If your root partition is created under `/mnt/@`, then you would need to mount the @cache subvolume.

Comment: A small summary can be found here: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Layout